# How to setup Danger js for code review automation in NextJS13 and Azure?

Tags: next.js13, danger

I want to integrate [danger js](https://danger.systems/js/tutorials/node-app) to improve our code review process for our NextJS project ( deployed on Azure ), however, I could not find a helpful resource to get started with NextJS and Azure.

I created a `dangerfile.ts` file:

```
import {message, danger} from "danger"

const modifiedMD = danger.git.modified_files.join("- ")
message("Changed Files in this PR: \n - " + modifiedMD)
```

However, I blocked what the next steps should be to continue the integration.